# My attempt in Hartshorne's exercise II.1.21.(d)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In this question, $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Italic words are definitions that come from Hartshorne's Algebraic geometry section I.3 and II.1 (If you need them, leave a comment).

**Part of the Exercise II.1.21(d)**

Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and let $\mathcal{O}$ be the sheaf of *regular functions*. Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the *constant sheaf* on $X$ associated to the *function field* $K$ of $X$. Show that the *quotient sheaf* $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of sheaves $\sum_{p\in X}i_P(K/\mathcal{O}_P)$ ($\mathcal{O}_P$ is the *local ring* of $P$), where $i_P(K/\mathcal{O}_P)$ denotes the *skyscraper sheaf* given by $K/\mathcal{O}_P$ at the point $P$.

**Some settings**

Since $X$ is irreducible, it is connected. Thus $\mathcal{K}(U)\cong K$. So I will identify $\mathcal{K}(U)$ with $K$. I will write $\langle U,f\rangle\in K$ for an element of $\mathcal{K}(U)=K$ (meaning $f:U\rightarrow k$ an regular function).

There is a natural injection $\mathcal{O}\rightarrow\mathcal{K}$ given by $\mathcal{O}(U)\ni(f:U\rightarrow k)\mapsto \langle U,f\rangle\in\mathcal{K}(U)$ so $\mathcal{K}/\mathcal{O}$ is defined well.

**My problem**

My strategy is finding a morphism of sheaves $\phi:\mathcal{K}\rightarrow \sum_{P\in X}i_P(K/\mathcal{O}_P)$ and use $\mathcal{K}/\ker\phi\cong\operatorname{im}\phi$. My problem occurs in defining $\phi(U):\mathcal{K}(U)\rightarrow \sum_{P\in X}i_P(K/\mathcal{O}_P)(U)=\sum_{P\in U} K/\mathcal{O}_P$. I think this map is $\langle V,f\rangle\mapsto \sum_{P\in U} \langle V,f\rangle+\mathcal{O}_P$. However, in my definition, $\langle V,f\rangle+\mathcal{O}_P=0$ for all but finitely many $P\in U$ because $\sum_{p\in X}i_P(K/\mathcal{O}_P)$ is the direct sum of sheaves (Equivalently $\langle V,f\rangle\in \mathcal{O}_P$ for all but finitely many $P\in U$.).

I wonder if there is any other way to define $\phi$ or $\sum_{P\in U} \langle V,f\rangle+\mathcal{O}_P$ is a sum of finite terms.

Comment: You indeed have to show that $\sum_{P\in U}\langle V,f\rangle+\mathcal{O}_P$ is a finite sum. In other words, that $f\in \mathcal{O}_P$ for all but finitely many $P$.

Comment: The proof of this statement has been covered before on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678077/morphism-between-quotient-sheaf-k-x-mathcalo-x-and-bigoplus-x-in-m/3678370#3678370). If that resolves your questions, please let me know.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. That solves my question.